# How to get the binary of a digit truncated to first 5 binary digits

Tags: java

i'm editing my question because it was not written correctly and confusing to understand what I was asking and I apologize. I read how i'm supposed to present a question and hope this is acceptable.

So I finished the code and it works all I want to know and I hope this is ok to ask
is there any optimization I could make to the code. I just want to know for future code that I have to write and become a better programmer.

The program ask the user to input a 5 digit postal code and return binary into a barcode using | for 1 and : for 0. so I need to check 5 digits and the total sum of the digits needs to be a multiple of 10 called the check digit

```
switch(first){
  case "0":
  first = digit0;
  break;
  case "1":
  first = digit1;
  break;
  case "2":
  first = digit2;
  break;
  case "3":
  first = digit3;
  break;
   case "4":
  first = digit4;
  break;
   case "5":
  first = digit5;
  break;
   case "6":
  first = digit6;
  break;
   case "7":
  first = digit7;
  break;
   case "8":
  first = digit8;
  break;
   case "9":
  first = digit9;
  break; 
  }
```

I used this block of code and replicated it for the 5 digits and the check number from the digits. I then used methods for each digits and the check digit.

```
public static void first(String first){


   String place1 = first.substring(0,1);
   String place2 = first.substring(1,2);
   String place3 = first.substring(2,3);
   String place4 = first.substring(3,4);
   String place5 = first.substring(4,5);

   switch(place1){
   case "0": 
   place1 = ":";
   break;
   case "1": 
   place1 = "|";
   break;
   }

   switch(place2){
   case "0": 
   place2 = ":";
   break;
   case "1": 
   place2 = "|";
   break;
   }

   switch(place3){
   case "0": 
   place3 = ":";
   break;
   case "1": 
   place3 = "|";
   break;
   }

   switch(place4){
   case "0": 
   place4 = ":";
   break;
   case "1": 
   place4 = "|";
   break;
   }

   switch(place5){
   case "0": 
   place5 = ":";
   break;
   case "1": 
   place5 = "|";
   break;
   }

  System.out.print("|" + place1 + place2 + place3 + place4 + place5);
  }
```

I then replicated this for each of the digits. I just would like to know if this is the right way to do a problem like this or there is more of an efficient way.
like maybe an if statement or something like that. I don't need the exact details just the types of way about going about it.

Again i apologize if this is incorrect way of asking about things on stack and if it is would like to know why. I appreciate your time and effort thank you.

Comment: Are you supposed to convert each **DIGIT** to its equivalent binary?...or convert the zip code as a **WHOLE NUMBER** to binary?

Comment: I added the image of the assignment

Comment: Your image is irrelevant to the question. Because 1) It's not legible. 2) We're not here to do your homework for you. If you want us to read that piece of paper, rewrite it respecting English grammar as much as possible (capitalize `I`) and use apostrophes. I recommend you to instead explain the problem with your own words, what you've tried and reply to @Idle_Mind as he has pointed out something that you **SHOULD** know already as this is **your** assignment! We're volunteers, willing to help you, but you need to show us that you care about this, help us to help you.

Comment: I am not harassing you nor attacking your question. I did improve it. But if you can't accept any feedback and follow the site rules, then there's nothing else to do. I'm downvoting and voting to close as "Unclear what you're asking" since OP doesn't seem to want to improve the question so it fits the [ask] rules.

Comment: @Idle_Mind i am trying to convert each digit to its binary

Comment: what did i do wrong?

Comment: why `int digit1 = 00011`, what kind of convention are you following?  Note that literals starting with a leading zero is octal, so the value is decimal 9.

Comment: @karakfa It's the encoding scheme presented in the image.

Comment: You should probably just go with the hardcoded strings. The method they used to select the digit encodings is more complicated than just binary conversion, and they give you the 10 possible strings right there, I don't think they expect you to regenerate them on your own.

Comment: For your new (edited) question, I recommend you to post a new one as it's completely different from the original one and this question is closed and it's not going to be reopen IMO, as it's completely different from the original one.

Comment: You could use `Integer.toBinaryString()` for a single digit, make the result 5-character wide, perhaps with `String.format()` and `%5s`, the replace spaces, zeroes and ones using `String.replaceAll()`

Answer (score 2):

In Java, numeric literals that start with a 0 is in **octal** (base 8), not decimal (base 10), so your numbers are:

```
int digit1 = 00011; // Decimal:     9   Hex:    9   Octal:    11
int digit2 = 00101; // Decimal:    65   Hex:   41   Octal:   101
int digit3 = 00110; // Decimal:    72   Hex:   48   Octal:   110
int digit4 = 01001; // Decimal:   513   Hex:  201   Octal:  1001
int digit5 = 01010; // Decimal:   520   Hex:  208   Octal:  1010
int digit6 = 01100; // Decimal:   576   Hex:  240   Octal:  1100
int digit7 = 10001; // Decimal: 10001   Hex: 2711   Octal: 23421
int digit8 = 10010; // Decimal: 10010   Hex: 271a   Octal: 23432
int digit9 = 10100; // Decimal: 10100   Hex: 2774   Octal: 23564
int digit0 = 11000; // Decimal: 11000   Hex: 2af8   Octal: 25370
```

Comment: Sorry i used the wrong format for the code and not a string for digit1 - 9. im sorry to all for making a bad post.